# Ruby on Rails Database Niling

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord, null

So, I have my database, but whenever I call `Model.create(:thing => "Hi")` it just "does it". When I look at it, my records are All `nil`s! (Minus the ID and Timestamp, those are managed by active record.) Is it the way I create them or IS it my model??? I am using Rails 4.0.1, and it's corresponding active record version.  So, what is it? What problems could create this?

My logs:irb(main):003:0>

```
Email.create(:user => User.find(3), :email => "HIDDEN@HIDDEN.HIDDEN", :key => Email.gen("gemist", "HIDDEN@HIDDEN.HIDDEN"))
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 3]]
WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes for Email: user, email, key

   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (2.9ms)  INSERT INTO "emails" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?)  [["created_at", Wed, 01 Jan 2014 21:22:24 UTC +00:00], ["updated_at", Wed, 01 Jan 2014 21:22:24 UTC +00:00]]
   (1.0ms)  commit transaction
=> #<Email id: 3, email: nil, User_id: nil, key: nil, confirmed: nil, created_at: "2014-01-01 21:22:24", updated_at: "2014-01-01 21:22:24">
```

And my model, incase you are wonder about ZE Generate function.... or anything else

```
class Email < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :User
  def self.gen(user,email)
    # Make conf keys on demand
    # Salting is used for randominzg and uniquisng, in the case we have already
    # sent keys to the same email (We don't want the samekeys more than once!)
    # Comboing to make sure that incase of two users who want to confirm the 
    # same email
    salt = BCrypt::Engine.generate_salt
    combo = user + email 
    return BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(combo, salt)
  end
end
```

I can offer a Migration or schmea if needed.

Now I know under "How to edit" I need to respect the original author, but I have no self respect.

Comment: Try `Model.create!(:thing => "Hi")`, which throws an exception if the instance is not successfully created. Post what this returns.

Comment: That probably isn't going to help much. The records are apparently persisting based on The Gemist saying the ID and timestamps are _not_ nil. Can you show us your model code and an example of you creating one?

Comment: Also can you show your controller code, and the output of the web server when you create something? Shot in the dark: Do you have all of your params whitelisted in a Strong Parameters block like `params.require(:thing).permit(:attribute1, :attribute2)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question contains the answer already:

```
WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes for Email: user, email, key
```

and:

```
INSERT INTO "emails" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?)  [["created_at", Wed, 01 Jan 2014 21:22:24 UTC +00:00], ["updated_at", Wed, 01 Jan 2014 21:22:24 UTC +00:00]]
```

You can't set `user`, `email`, and `key` during a mass-assignment (which `create()` is doing), so it's ignoring those. The only fields being set, as you can see from the `INSERT` log, are the timestamp fields. So you end up with a fairly empty record in the database.

You can set those fields individually on a model instance, or you can flag them as mass-assignable by putting this in your model:

```
attr_accessible :user, :email, :key
```

You may very well want to leave them protected, though. Here's an [article on mass-assignment protection](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ruby/mass-assignment-rails-and-you/). If you're processing form data, you probably want to leave the protection in place for certain fields. If your `create()` is already using trusted data, you can make them accessible.

Comment: Yes, yes that was it. I was using Console, so I much prefer one liners there. Very good!

Comment: The OP said he is using Rails 4. If he wants to use `attr_accessible` needs to use the protected attributes gem - https://github.com/rails/protected_attributes.